# Publish a QML/C++ application as a click package

Tags: ubuntu-touch, c++, qml

I've written an application which I would like to publish as click package. All the guides and prepared projects mention plain QML applications only.

My application furthermore depends on a shared library (TagLib in my case). Is there any guide which I could follow?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using cmake or qmake?

Comment: I use qmake. Basically everything QtCreator offers. I use the version from Ubuntu SDK on Linux.